# Magento: Move product group info to the bottom in the product view

Tags: xml, magento, themes

I'm trying without success to move a block with is referenced in the catalog.xml file:

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped translate="label" module="catalog">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Grouped)</label>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_type_grouped"   name="product.info.grouped" as="product_type_data"  template="catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
```

I want to move the "product.info.grouped" block to the bottom of the product view page (only for grouped products). I have tried adding after="-" to the block, but nothing happens. This block shows a table of related products, which would like to appear below the media section and additional info.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving it in the template itself? The XML hierarchy on Magento pages doesn't seem to be geared towards this kind of switch, whereas the layout PHTML files are very much geared toward it.